# Is there a way to apply a filldown formula for a dynamic range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to apply a formula to Column E which is a dynamic range. The formula I would like to use is in E6 and I need a way to create a 'fill down' VBA code to apply this formula to new cells in the rows as they are added.

As users add new rows of data to Column E, the formula `=D6*$X$4` needs to be dragged down, but I will not know how many additional rows there will be. Also, the headers finish at Row 5 so the range will start at Row 6 and go downward.

Any way to go about this? Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Comment: Use a table - Ctrl+T.

Comment: **1.** Find last row in column E as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) **2.** Enter formula in the entire range in one go. `Range("E6:E" & lastRow).Formula = "=D6*$X$4"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you for feedback, this worked well!